# Unable to install MySQLdb module in pycharm for python 3.6

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pycharm, python-3.6, mysql-python

I have been trying to connect to `mysqldb` using `sqlalchemy` but I get an error about MySQLdb being not installed.

Below are the steps I've tried.

1. `pip install MySQLdb-python`: did not work saying Visual C++ 14.0 not installed, even though 14.0.2863 is installed in the machine and Visual Studio Tools 2017 have been installed
2. Tried installing `mysqldb` connector and tried to `pip install MySQLdb-python`; still the same error "Visual C++ 14.0 not installed"

I am trying to create a module to connect to various DBs and trying to do it through `sqlalchemy` but MySQLdb is creating a problem. Kindly help me to install MySQLdb module in PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

First download `mysql-python` from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python), and you got a `.whl` file(remember to mind the version).

Then install it using `pip.exe`.

For me, it is:

`E:\Python27\Scripts>pip.exe install MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: Thanks for your inputs IAMANGRY , but i am getting an error "MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform." is there something im missing

Comment: It says the file you downloaded does't conform to the platform. So you need to check your python interpreter, 32-bit version or 64-bit version?

Comment: Open your IDLE and see the information in the top. If it is 32-bit, what you need to download is `MySQL_python‑1.2.5‑cp27‑none‑win32.whl` 
 with no  `amd64` in the name

Comment: its 64 bit but not sure why its not getting installed. i am able to import MySQLdb in IDLE but not sure in pycharm